# Вместо скачивания файла с html страницы, копируется его html код

Tags: java, download

Пытаюсь скачать файл с помощью такого кода (и нескольких ему подобных) :

```
    URL website = new URL("https://rootgames.org/22-far-cry-3-2012-pc-rus-2.html/far.cry.3.torrent");
    ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("E:\\FarCry3.torrent");
    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

Но вместо торрент файла я получаю txt файл (только с расширением .torrent), в котором находится такой код

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://rootgames.org/22-far-cry-3-2012-pc- 
rus-2.html/far.cry.3.html">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

Причем содержимое файла вообще не зависит от того, что будет написано в url адресе после последнего разделителя "/".
P.S. Пример именно такой, ибо в данном случае самый короткий html код в скаченном файле, при скачивании чего либо с других сайтов количество html кода в моем файле доходило до бесконечности.

Comment: А кто сказал что по этому адресу есть торрент? Судя по страничке там 301 редирект

Comment: Так при переходе по ссылке файл скачивается на любом сайте. А через код java  - всегда txt с html кодом

Comment: Читайте в сторону `mime-type`